# "Could not find or load main class @tag" error when running my tests from IntelliJ IDE

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, tags, ide

I am trying to run my tests using a Junit configuration , in IntelliJ IDE.
I am setting up the configuration and I insert my VM options , into which I am using a tag to run specific tests.
When I click on the "Run" button I get the following error: ""Error:Could not find or load main class @tag"
I have no clue what is wrong.Has anyone encountered the same issue?

Screenshot 1-configuration
[image: Screenshot 1-configuration]

VM-Options
[image: VM-Options]

Comment: Please attach a screenshot of your run configuration.

Comment: added in the original post

Comment: Will it work if you switch "Test kind" to Tags?

Comment: Unfortunatelly that didn't work.I keep getting the same error.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that you should leave only "-ea" in VM options when you switch  to "Tags". If it doesn't help please share some sample project for investigation.